# Why is my site zooming into my .wrapper div when viewed on an iphone?

Tags: ios, css, html

I changed this site over to html5 using the html5 boilerplate.  Everything looks fine when viewed on a desktop or even an ipad but when I view it on my iphone it zooms in only showing the contents of my .wrapper div.  I've tried removing the 
 as many have suggested.  I also tried adding maximum-scale-1.0, initial-scale=1.0, and minimum-scale=1.0 and none of these or combinations of them have solved the problem.  I also tried setting my body and html tags to width:100% with no luck. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is and if it's a css or meta tag problem. The site is located at www.sweetestgourmet.com.

Answer (score 0):

use css3 media queries

include meta tag as show in the **head tag**

then in stylesheet taget iphone as

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){

   /* write your css */
 }
```

here is tutorial http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: thankyou for your advice, i will try to implement form next time.

Comment: thanks this worked to stop the logo from being cut off on the left by adding 90px of margin however there is no margin on the right, except on the contact page. Why is the margins only working on one of the pages? Also it's still zoomed in when in portrait, look fine in landscape. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to `<head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`